# Does this property really characterize monomorphisms?

Tags: category-theory, monomorphisms

In the post [Does this property characterize monomorphisms?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1192719/does-this-property-characterize-monomorphisms), I do not see how the third condition is equivalent to the others. Specifically, I require that $k_0$ *and* $k_1$ be isomorphisms in order that the third conidition is equivalent to the others. Could someone please explain this? I understand the others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third condition can only hold with $k_1=k_0$, and then their common inverse $t$ will give an isomorphism of this pullback with the one whose tip and legs are $A$ with its identities, as in the second condition.

Indeed, given a pullback square of the form in the third condition we should have a factorization $g:A\to K$ of the following square through $K$.
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A @>{\mathrm{id}}>> A \\
@V{\mathrm{id}}VV @VV{f}V \\
A @>>{f}> B
\end{CD}$$

Then $k_0g=\mathrm{id}_A$, so $g=t$, but $k_1g=k_t=\mathrm{id}_A$, so $k_1=k_0,$ as claimed.

Comment: this shows how the fourth condition implies the first. I'm interested in how the third is equivalent to any of the others.

Comment: Oops, miscounted. Thank you.

Comment: Is this not a proof of the second implies the fourth? What I'm really getting at, is that the third condition as it is written in [Does this property characterize monomorphisms?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1192719/does-this-property-characterize-monomorphisms) is _not_ in fact equivalent to the other three. That is, it is not enough that we have at least one of $k_0$ and $k_1$ is an isomorphism. It is necessary that _both_ are isomorphisms. In such a case then certainly $k_0$ = $k_1$. Thanks

Comment: No. This is a proof that the third condition implies the second. I edited to clarify this

Comment: I'm so sorry, I'm still not sure what you are assuming, and what you are concluding. The statement of condition three does not include the assumption that $k_0$ and $k_1$ have a common inverse $t$. It is simply the condition that at least one of $k_0$ and $k_1$ is an isomorphism. Thus apparently we should get that the third condition is equivalent to the others even in the case that only one of $k_0$ and $k_1$ is an isomorphism. Moreover, how can you say $g$ exists? The condition is that $K$ is the assumed pullback object, not $A$. Thanks

Comment: The claim is that condition three *implies* that the two $k$s have a common inverse, as I prove in the second paragraph. $g$ is exactly the kind of map that $K$ being a pullback gives you...every pair of maps to $A$ equalized to $f$ factors through $K$. In this case, the pair of two identities on $A$.